# why do i get error of alpr even after installing openalpr on my raspberry pi 3?

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi3, debian-jessie, openalpr, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I'm trying to use openalpr for recognizing number plates of moving vehicles from a video using raspberry pi 3 with jessie os. I have installed tesseract 3,OpenCV3 and Openalpr. I have installed following this link: 
 https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/wiki/Compilation-instructions-(Ubuntu-Linux) . when i use `"alpr --help "`, terminal displays `"bash:alpr:command not found"`

Comment: If you haven't already, you should probably ask the question in the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.